# Get user's current external transfer limits

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

Ultimately I am trying to set limits for external transfers on specific users accounts, but before I set the limits of external transfers, I need to check their current limits to make sure they are not being lowered by my change.

I am not seeing any options to retrieve this data, has anyone been able to retrieve a users external transfer limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the Consumer API address to find the user's abilities. You must now the Banno ID code for the specific user and your institution ID. The endpoint is in the following format: {{consumerUrl}}/users/:userId/institutions/:institutionId. The information is in root/externalTransferSettings in the REST response:

"externalTransferSettings": {
"inboundFee": "0.00",
"outboundFee": "0.00",
"currentDailyInboundTotal": "0.00",
"currentDailyOutboundTotal": "0.00",
"currentDailyInboundQuantity": 0,
"currentDailyOutboundQuantity": 0,
"cutOffTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"additionalMessage": "Transfers may be subjected to a hold for up to seven business days. ",
"inboundHighRiskThreshold": null,
"outboundHighRiskThreshold": null,
"dailyInboundLimit": "2500.00",
"dailyOutboundLimit": "2500.00",
"dailyInboundQuantitativeLimit": 10,
"dailyOutboundQuantitativeLimit": 10
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you!! I'm not sure how I didn't see that as an option

Comment: @Ben Reavis, ignore the shade thrown by the bot, lol

Comment: That's a good answer, it is indeed within [GET /users/{userId}/institutions/{institutionId}](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/institutions/details/#/User-Specific%20Institution%20Abilities/fetchUserAbilities)

Comment: @RyanWiebe I had to think about this one (and am glad Ben Reavis had an answer ready to go) and ended up searching for "external transfer settings" via the search bar in the docs. So that's also a good way to find info which may not be easy to find.